# Which is the latest version of R language that supports package Rfacebook?

Tags: r

When i tried to install Rfacebook in the latest version of R i got an error saying that Rfacebook is not available for this version of R language. Iam using an ubuntu system and i want to install R languange with R facebook package.

Comment: I see that is is available for the current version of R .... what are you seeing when trying to install it on your undescribed OS and version of R?

Answer (score 1):

This question will likely get closed soon but in a nutshell you want to

- look at the [CRAN page for RFacebook](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/Rfacebook/index.html)
- it states `Depends:   R (≥ 2.12.0), httr, rjson, httpuv`
- R greater than 2.12.0 is not likely to be a problem
- *but* the other depends may be

The answer, however, is also simple: Go read [R on Ubuntu README at CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html)
and follow its steps to install the current version of R.

Then install Rfacebook. It will "just work".